# $.ajax function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: base_url + "/stats/add.json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data_stat) ,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg.message);
    }
});

alert("other");
```

It only post data when there is `alert("other")`.

Comment: `$.ajax` is asynchronous and the `alert()` is blocking the UI from updating. The code is working fine, your logic may need changing to suit your requirements though.

Comment: You can try with async:false.

Comment: @RamasamyKanna ***never use `async: false`***. It locks the UI thread until the request completes, so it appears to the user as though their browser has crashed.

Comment: if you want to see message in the browser you could log it in console: `console.log(msg.message)`

Comment: are you using this in `$(document).ready(function(){ // your code here })`

Comment: may be http://codingbin.com/get-return-data-ajax-call/ can help you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BUT** if you want to definitely alert your message it can be done in `.done()` without blocking main UI

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: base_url + "/stats/add.json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data_stat) ,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(msg){
        //Blocks main UI because of the reason Rocy McCrossan told you
        alert(msg.message);
    },
}).done(function(msg) { 
      alert(msg.message);
});
```